# Adjoint of $T_A = Ax$

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators

Is it true that if $T_A(x) = Ax$ then $T^*_A(x) = A^*x$?  I tried to prove this for the standard inner product
$$
\newcommand{\innp}[2]{\left\langle #1,#2 \right\rangle}
\innp{Ax}{x} = x^tA^t\overline{x} = x^t\overline{A^*}\overline{x} = \innp{x}{A^*x}
$$

but I can't seem to prove for a general inner product.
Is it true? How do I generalize this for any inner product?

Comment: When your vector space is equipped with an inner product, then the adjoint is defined with this inner product. Modifying the inner product modifies the pre-hilbert space.

Answer (score 1):

Note that any inner product on $\def\C{\mathbf C}\C^n$ has the form 
$$ \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<x,y>_B = x^t B\bar y $$
for some hermitian positive $B$. ($B$ has the entries $b_{ij} = \<e_i, e_j>_B$). To compute the matrix of the adjoint of multiplication by $B$, we can argue as follows:
\begin{align*}
  \<Ax, y>_B &= x^tA^t B\bar y\\
             &= x^t \overline{\bar A^t B^t} \bar y \\
             &= x^t B\overline{\bar B^{-1}\bar A^t B^t y}\\
             &= \<x, B^{-t}\bar A^t B^t y>
\end{align*}
So the matrix of $T_A^*$ (adjoint with respect to $\<,>_B$) for the standard basis is $B^{-t}\bar A^t B^t$.